# Can you say "or something" after a place or time?

Tags: grammaticality

People often say *or something* to finish an already complete sentence, mostly in a question.

For example: *Did you dye your hair or something?*

I wonder if that can be said when you mention a place or time. Like, *Aren’t you from Burma or something?* Or *Didn’t you arrive at nine or something?*

I can think of replacing it with *somewhere*  and *sometime* respectively but somehow that doesn’t go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use, 'or something' for a place or time. What it means is that you're not sure that you're correct about the information you are referring to.

However, I don't think it's wise to use this turn of phrase. Depending on your tone of voice it might give the impression that you either don't really care what the answer is at all or don't have much self-confidence in general. All three of your example questions can be asked without saying 'or something' and sound more respectful and more confident that way.

> Did you dye your hair?
> Aren't you from Burma?
> Didn't you arrive at nine?